# Sonata sandbox multi-sf installation

Tags: symfony, sonata

I would like to ask if anybody knows how to configure the multi-sf branch of the https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox repository for the first run.

My target is being able to run the 2.8 version.

What I did was running:

```
sh composer.sh sf2-8 install
```

in order to install the vendor folder. 
But after that, when trying to run the server

```
php app\console server:run
```

I obtained this error:

> "unable to detect the symfony version"

Thanks in advance

**Edit for who's interested on this sandbox:**

I don't know why I couldn't install the 2.8 symfony version of the sandbox via the multi_sf branch, but I could made it to work by simply cloning the 2.4-dev branch and just typing

```
composer install
```

after of course checking and satisfying the installation requirements by typing

```
php app\check.php
```

The symfony version that comes out by following these simple steps will be 2.8 .

Hope it will be useful for anybody diving into this partially-documented project.

Comment: If you type in the command `symfony` what does that show you?

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't know where should I run that command from; I cloned the repository as it is, and then tried running
    sh composer.sh sf2-8 install.

I didn't create the project from composer..
I also forgot to mention I'm under windows10

Comment: Just run from your bash shell. I just want to know if it returns anything or not.

Comment: No by now it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions to install Symfony. This is the problem you are experiencing:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications

That should work.
If you just type `symfony` from your shell, you will get the version of Symfony and all the various help commands.

Comment: Thanks for having spent some time trying to help me, but I tried that way and I couldn't made it to work. I found a solution which I posted on my original post, thanks again